# PostgreSQL trigger function taking too long leading to php timeout

Tags: php, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4

### Problem

I have a `plpgsql` function `prepare_download_file` that is passed in several user-defined parameters from a `php` script, inserts these parameters in to a log table `adc_query_log` and then uses them to build an `sql` query that selects a bunch of data, copies down the results to `csv` and finally returns a unique id which is needed in the `php` script. The `id` is a crucial part since the `php` script uses it to select the 3 output files, pack them in to a `.zip` archive, and send an email to the user with a download link.

Depending on the parameters, the query may execute pretty quickly, other times I've found that it takes longer than 45 seconds and times out as far as the `php` script is concerned so it doesn't get the unique id it needs.

### Proposed solution

Split the `prepare_download_file` function into two parts so that the first part only inserts the parameters in to the log table and returns the unique id, which should happen instantaneously (first column `id` is type `serial`):

```
INSERT INTO adc_query_log
  VALUES (DEFAULT,query_type,severity,year_range,local_authorities)
RETURNING id INTO session_id;
```

The second part `make_download_file()` is executed via a trigger function and returns `NULL`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER make_download_file AFTER INSERT ON adc_query_log
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_download_file();
```

which reads the inserted values from the table to build the `sql` query and then does all the heavy lifting - supposedly after the unique id has been returned to the `php` script.

### Question

Does the `RETURNING id INTO session_id` bit wait until the trigger function has completed before marking this transaction as complete and then returning the `id`? If not, is there a way I can force it not to wait?

Server is running `PostgreSQL 8.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement won't return until the trigger function has finished.

I would put the jobs that take a long time into a “queue” table and have a separate process that works off the jobs in the queue asynchronously. That way you don't have to worry about timeouts.

For communication between the processes, you can either pull the status regularly, or you can use PostgreSQL's `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`.

Comment: Just a side question: hasn't Postgres got a built-in event scheduler for just that purpose? Because MySQL has, and I've heard many odes sung to how Postgres is more advanced than MySQL.

Comment: There is no task scheduler in PostgreSQL. There are third-party tools like [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/pgagent.html).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ok so I'm thinking I can alter the log table to include a boolean `processed` column, then have a scheduled `cron` task for example that selects any records not marked as done and then works through them. or if you have any keywords I can search for how to do something like that within postgres please share!

Comment: The is the pgq extension that implements queues. You want three states: new, in progress, done. Otherwise two workers may try to process the same item.

Answer (score 0):

I 90% sure you will have to wait for trigger to end before get the id, so the timeout would happen again.

So in this case you should get the id ( as you say is almost instant ), and then make a second call to the store procedure using the id